# what will happen if I format the drive with ubuntu while in windows?

Tags: dual-boot, format

I have a dual boot windows-ubuntu and I am running out of Windows space. My ubuntu partition is atleast 200GB and now I need some of it, so I could have more space for windows. Can I format the drive containing ubuntu so I could reinstall ubuntu later? Will it cause problems when I boot into windows later?

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using dual boot. Which bootloader are you using? If you have installed ubuntu after windows installation, most probably 'grub' will be the boot loader, making it unable to boot windows if you format the ubuntu partition from windows.

Application like BCD can help you. Please see the following link. It might help you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heO1n73Ua4Q

Comment: What if I shrink the volume of the drive containing ubuntu by right-clicking This PC then manage then disk management ? Would it not work/damage my grub or windows? @ATR

Comment: The best option is to use `gparted` Live CD or 'ubuntu Live CD' itself.
Please note resize can't be made on mounted partition. So use Live CD. 
To install gparted use command `sudo apt-get install gparted` and run command `sudo gparted`. Following link might be helpful.

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd

Also see the thread:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1564519

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would want to manage your partition via Ubuntu with `GParted` app which I found to be very reliable.  You might would be able to assign the more volumes to Windows without hindering any OS otherwise.